# openiddict-core refresh_token using token issued by legacy code

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

We are in the process of porting an existing classic .net webapi project to .net core. One of the obsolete libraries being used is `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth`. Currently the best option as a replacement is `openiddict-core`.

One of the things I would like to implement is issuing a new `access_token/refresh_token` based on a refresh token that was issued by the previous version of the api. That way clients can gracefully swap out their refresh token once a new version of the api is deployed.

However, when I ask openiddict for a `refresh_token` with a value that was created by the previous version of the API, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "The specified refresh token is invalid."
}
```

By reading the code, I can see that the request is invalidated by the `ValidateReferenceTokenIdentifier` [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/blob/376cbad1e50b046459bc338882c37a7dcc538805/src/OpenIddict.Server/OpenIddictServerHandlers.cs#L330-L351) because it checks that the provided `refresh_token` actually exists in the database.

What would be the recommended way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

OpenIddict 3.0 includes native support for tokens produced by [ASOS](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) and OpenIddict 1.x/2.x, that use ASP.NET Core Data Protection. The Katana OAuth 2.0 authorization server middleware, when hosted on IIS/System.Web, uses ASP.NET Machine Keys, which is a completely different stack and is not supported on .NET Core/.NET 5.0.

Consider adopting the new format: users will have to re-authenticate to get a new refresh token, but it's generally not a blocking issue. Otherwise, use the events model to implement custom token validation. See https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/tree/dev/src/OpenIddict.Server.DataProtection for some inspiration.